# ContentType fails to be sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my app I have this code. I noticed, that content-type fails to be sent. Do you know how to force sending it?

```
$.ajax({                                                                   
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://serv/services/rest/contact/' + localStorage.getItem('contact'), 
        callback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonp: '_jsonp',
        **contentType:  'application/json',**
        dataType: 'jsonp json',
        timeout : 10000,

        success: function(data){
            $("#name").attr("value", data.response.label);
        }           },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Status: " + xhr.status + ", Ajax option: " + ajaxOptions + ", Thrown error: " + thrownError);
        },
    });
```

My request header is:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=F0ED33279488888888B35A731B40EE0C; oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=789456321
Host:serv
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)                   Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1
```

As I said, contentType is missing. What am I missing?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set Content-Type if you are POSTing data. So you will need to change:

```
type: 'POST'
```

You perhaps are looking to tell the server what you accept in response try:

```
accepts: 'application/json'
```

See here [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to make a cross domain reqest, so I have to use JSONP, which requires type:get. I will simply change a server side not to require contenttype.

Comment: No problem hope you get it sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need content type for requests.

Change your `dataType` to `json` like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://serv/services/rest/contact/' + localStorage.getItem('contact'), 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $("#name").attr("value", data.response.label);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("Status: " + xhr.status + ", Ajax option: " + ajaxOptions + ", Thrown error: " + thrownError);
    }
});
```

Instead return your data as `JSON`.

I did notice your `crossDomain: true,`, for that to work you need to read [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea), more exactly add this header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com` in response.

As an example for PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
```

Example for `.htaccess`

```perl
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to use JSONP instead of JSON. I have already dealed with the cross-domain, the problem was in server response. Server required contenttype, and according to what @scott said, I am unable to send it.